# Render dynamic animated editable text

Tags: ffmpeg, glsl, webgl, mlt

I am working on one web application development where i need to render glsl which can support editable animated text.
Whereas User can edit the animated text which can be rendered through webgl.

Can you please provide me and reference link or if there any working GLSL code where i can pass editable text as input?

eg. I want to have same animation as provided in the below link using glsl
https://tobiasahlin.com/moving-letters/#1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956272/better-quality-text-in-webgl

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in WebGL to directly display text.

The easiest way to do this would be to write text in a 2D canvas and use it as a texture in your WebGL scene.